# Assign a value to array by index in Liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am inside of a bit complex loops and I need to assign a value to an array by index, so that if the value is already there it will replace it, if not it will create it.

So I need to do something like this:

```
{% assign arr = '' | split: '' %}
{% assign arr[index] = value %}
```

which is not working, the array is still empty.

Is there any workaround to do this?

Answer (score 3):

There is no direct workaround.

You can always re-create the array with a default value though that would only give you a single value.

One potential work around would be to re-create the source and fill in any missing defaults then re-split into an array

```
{% assign arr = someValue | split: '' %} <!-- splitting to single chars ? -->
{% assign withDefaults = '' %}
{% for ...%}
  {% unless arr[loop.index0] == true %}
  {% withDefaults = withDefaults | append : 'defaultValue,' %}
  {% else %}
  {% withDefaults = withDefaults | append : arr[loop.index0] | append : ',' %}
{% endfor %}
{% assign arr = withDefaults | split: ',' %} <!-- you'll have an extra blank element but that may not matter -->
```

Comment: I couldn't find that fact in their documentation. Can you? Anyhow, really important information!