# Is there a way to increment array variables in liquid?

Tags: arrays, shopify, liquid

Here's some simple code:

```
{% assign mine = '1,2,3' | split: ',' %}
{{ mine[2] }}
{% assign mine[2] = mine[2] | plus: 2 %}
{{ mine[2] }}
```

In both cases it outputs 3. How do I make it add 2 to the third variable of the array without re-assigning the whole array? Second output should be 5.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do math with Liquid? Could you accomplish your goals without a clunky fake array? Since you don't show what this code is used for, could it be that you could do the math in JS after Liquid renders and use that? I am thinking you are not going to be able to do the math you want, like this. Maybe if you were to introduce yet another variable? No matter. It'll be clunky that way too.

Comment: The math is not the problem. The problem is that is not possible to assign a value inside an array. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47835139/assign-a-value-to-array-by-index-in-liquid